# Hover Effect Triggering on Seperate Elements Simultaneously

Tags: css, node.js, arrays, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm mapping over an array of objects.
The Array is:

```
const socialLinks = [
    {
      id: 1,
      child: (
        <>
          <FaLinkedin className='text-2xl' /> Linkedin
        </>
      ),
      href: 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/',
      style: 'rounded-tl-lg'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      child: (
        <>
          <FaGithub className='text-2xl' /> Github
        </>
      ),
      href: 'https://github.com/7'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      child: (
        <>
          <FaMailBulk className='text-2xl' /> Mail
        </>
      ),
      href: 'mailto:'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      child: (
        <>
          <FaPersonBooth className='text-2xl' /> Resume
        </>
      ),
      href: '',
      style: 'rounded-bl-lg'
    }
  ]
```

Then I map over the array and return li for each object which is wrapped around ul 
The Map Function:

```
        {socialLinks.map(({ child, href, style = '', download = '', id }) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={id}
              className={
                'flex justify-between items-center h-14 w-40 px-4 bg-stone-700/80 mr-[-100px] hover:mr-[-10px] hover:rounded-lg duration-300' +
                ' ' +
                style
              }
            >
              <Link
                key={id}
                href={href}
                download={download}
                target='_blank'
                rel='noreferrer'
                className='flex justify-between items-center w-full'
              >
                {child}
              </Link>
            </li>
          )
        })}
```

Now,
Hovering over any one li element expands(or reduces margin) for all li element. I expect only the hovered element to expand.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margins push the whole containing element and affect the layout. Instead, you could consider using `transform: translateX()` instead:

```js
const socialLinks = [
    {
      id: 1,
      child: 'Linkedin',
      href: 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/',
      style: 'rounded-tl-lg'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      child: 'Github',
      href: 'https://github.com/7'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      child: 'Mail',
      href: 'mailto:'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      child: 'Resume',
      href: '',
      style: 'rounded-bl-lg'
    }
  ]


const Link = ({ children, ...props }) => <a {...props}>{children}</a>

function App() {
  return (
    <ul class="fixed right-0">
      {socialLinks.map(({ child, href, style = '', download = '', id }) => {
        return (
         <li
           key={id}
           className={'flex justify-between items-center h-14 w-40 px-4 bg-stone-700/80 translate-x-[100px] hover:translate-x-[10px] hover:rounded-lg duration-300' + ' ' + style}
         >
           <Link
              key={id}
              href={href}
              download={download}
              target='_blank'
              rel='noreferrer'
              className='flex justify-between items-center w-full'
            >
              {child}
            </Link>
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```